# Getting error when using JWT, also want to send JWT token to other APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, postman

I am implementing JWT in node js/express js:

Here is my code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const secretCode = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
const refreshCode = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');


function generateAccessTokens(user){
    return jwt.sign({user}, secretCode, {expiresIn: '30m', });
}


function refreshAccessTokens(user) {
    return jwt.sign({user}, refreshCode); //refresh code should never expire
}


function verifyToken(request, response, next){
    //let's access the authorization header
    const authHeader = request.headers['authorization'];  
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];    
    if(token === null || typeof(token) === "undefined"){
        //tell the user you do not have access
        response.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized Access!"});
    }

    //if token is not null then
    jwt.verify(token, secretCode, (error, user) =>{
        if(error) return response.status(403).json({message: "Forbidden Access:Token Expired!"});

        //if the user is verified
        request.user = user;
        next(); //move on
    });
}
```

I am protecting this route by including verifyToken as a middleware.
This is the route, where I am getting the error:

```
router.get('/list', verifyToken , (request, response) =>{
    try{
        let listRequestToken = request.token;
        jwt.verify(listRequestToken, secretCode, (err, authData) =>{
            if(err){
                response.status(403).json({message: `You do not have access ${error}`});
            }else{
                let myOTPCodeList = await otpCodeModel.find();
                return response.status(202).json(myOTPCodeList, authData);
            }
        });

    }catch(error){
        return response.status(400).json({message: `Error Occurred:\n${error}`});
    }
});
```

I am getting "Could not get response" from Postman.

[image: Postman Error Message]

Getting the following error in the terminal:

```
{
    "message": "You do not have access JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided"
}
```

**Question 1:**
How to fix the above error ?

**Question 2:**
What is the best way to send the jwt token to other REST APIs ?

Comment: where does "jwt must be provided" error come from? edit: oh, right, from `jwt.verify` - at a guess, `let listRequestToken = request.token;` is `undefined` due to the fact that you're sending in a reqeust header (Authorization) and expecting it on the request object as `token` property ... how would it get there?

Comment: you're adding user to request, but not token - but if `verifyToken` already verifies the token, you don't need to verify it again in router.get

Comment: yes, you'll know it's verifies if `response` has `user` property, that the middleware (verifyToken) put there when the token was already verified

Answer (score 0):

```
function verifyToken(request, response, next){
    //let's access the authorization header
    const authHeader = request.headers['authorization'];  
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];    
    if(token === null || typeof(token) === "undefined"){
        //tell the user you do not have access
        response.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized Access!"});
    }

    //if token is not null then
    jwt.verify(token, secretCode, (error, user) =>{
        if(error) return response.status(403).json({message: "Forbidden Access:Token Expired!"});

        //if the user is verified
        request.user = user;
        next(); //move on
    });
}
```

This code is already verifying the token, and setting `request.user = user`

Then you do:

```
    let listRequestToken = request.token; // this will be undefined
    jwt.verify(listRequestToken, secretCode, (err, authData) =>{
        if(err){
            response.status(403).json({message: `You do not have access ${error}`});
        }else{
            let myOTPCodeList = await otpCodeModel.find();
            return response.status(202).json(myOTPCodeList, authData);
        }
    });
```

This code is using `verifyToken` to verify the token. If it's verified `request` will have `user` property

At no point is `token` property added to `request`

so

1. you're calling jwt.verify with a `undefined` token
2. you don't need to call `jwt.verify` again, since it's been done
3. you need to access the header using `request.get('Authorization')`

So, just add a `return` to `response.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized Access!"});`

```
function verifyToken(request, response, next){
    //let's access the authorization header
    const authHeader = request.get('Authorization'); // ****
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];    
    if(token === null || typeof(token) === "undefined"){
        //tell the user you do not have access
        return response.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized Access!"}); // ****
    }

    //if token is not null then
    jwt.verify(token, secretCode, (error, user) =>{
        if(error) return response.status(403).json({message: "Forbidden Access:Token Expired!"});

        //if the user is verified
        request.user = user;
        next(); //move on
    });
}
```

and

```
router.get('/list', verifyToken , (request, response) =>{
    try{
        if(!request.user){
            response.status(403).json({message: `You do not have access ${error}`});
        }else{
            let myOTPCodeList = await otpCodeModel.find();
            return response.status(202).json(myOTPCodeList, request.user);
        }
    }catch(error){
        return response.status(400).json({message: `Error Occurred:\n${error}`});
    }
});
```

`jwt.verify` in `verifyToken` you have the callback argument named `user`

`jw.verify` in the `route.get` you have the callback argument named `authData`

of course, these two results are the same data, just the variable name is different, so `response.name` is the same as what you expected `authData` to be

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's telling me "Unauthorized Access!", meaning that it's undefined or null as per my verifyToken function

Comment: how did my code change make the error happen earlier? that's just bizarre

Comment: add a `console.log(token)` just after `const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];`

Comment: @abc123 I see the last problem now - that error was probably masked because you didn't `return response.status(401)` as the other answer pointed out

Comment: I returned, but still, and when I console.log(token) I get undefined

Comment: did you see the update ... regarding `you need to access the header using request.get('Authorization')` @abc123

Comment: I did, but still getting undefined

Comment: what about `authHeader` - what is its value

Comment: undefined as well.

Comment: if that's undefined then of course token is undefined - now you know the Authorization header isn't even being received (or is it not even sent?) according to docs, the value you put in request.get is case-insensitive .... but try `request.get('authorization');` in case the documentation is lying :p